# Why do i get this error: Swagger UI 404 error on SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger, swagger-ui

Hello everyone i have a problem with Swagger ui. Actually my code was working and i could see the Swagger UI but i can't see now and i didn't change anything.
I got the error this when i refresh the page on Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

My SpringFoxConfigClass:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>

            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: And i see this on **localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html**


`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 01 13:21:25 TRT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving 404 error on Swagger UI with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814372/receiving-404-error-on-swagger-ui-with-spring)